# 3D surface plotting with multiple samples

Tags: python, plot, 3d, geometry-surface

I have a CSV file that has multiple rows and columns. For example, suppose I have the following CSV (tab delimited) file:

```
    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5
Log1    2.3 3.3 4.5 5.6 6.7
Log2    3.5 6.7 10.0    22.1    30
Log3    4.2 4.5 6.7 8.9 9.1
Log4    4.5 8.9 10.2    11.8    14.7
```

I've checked the surface plot methods in pylab library at [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-4-Matplotlib.ipynb), but I feel what I want to do is different from the examples they give. Because I want my X-axis to be the names in the first column of the CSV (Log1, Log2...Log4), and the Y-axis to show the column names (e.g. Sample1, Sample2, ... Sample5). The values will determine how the surface looks like in the 3D plot.

So I was wondering how to make the 3D surface plotting in python or any other tools? any reply will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Thanks to @anon's answer below, I wrote the following python code, but I am not clear how to assign the values from my CSV file to the (X, Y, Z) coordinates. The way I am doing it below is to assign the X, Y values by the size of x_axis (a list of X labels) and the size of y_axis(a list of Y labels), the Z value is the actual numbers from my CSV file. But my code below does not work - need some extra help with it.

```
csv_file_path='/path/to/my/CSV/my_file.csv'    
mFile = open(csv_file_path, 'rb')
datafile = list(csv.reader(mFile, delimiter='\t'))

x_ax = []  # a list of X labels
y_ax = []  # a list of Y labels
row_data = []  # a list of row values 
Z = []     # a list of row_data


first_line = True  # skip the first line which is the header

for row in datafile:
    print row[0]
    summ = 0

    if first_line:
        y_ax = row[1:]
        print y_ax
        first_line = False
        continue

    x_ax.append(row[0])
    row_data = row[1:]
    data.append(row_data)

X = range(len(x_ax))   # use the length of x_ax as the X coordinate
Y = range(len(y_ax))   # use the length of y_ax as the Y coordinate


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(200, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ax)
ax.set_title("Frequencies Surface Plotting")

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, data, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(0, 100)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink = 0.5, aspect = 5)

plt.show()
```

**examples from Pylab:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `x` and `y` axis labels to be what you want. For example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
x_ax = ["Log1", "Log2"] # etc ... just parse what you need from the CSV file
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ax)
y_ax = ["Sample1","Sample2"] # etc... just parse what you need from the CSV file
ax.set_yticklabels(y_ax)
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image: Changed axis]

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I seem to have more questions regarding the plotting. So, I wrote the following code to read in my CSV file, and populate the X-axis label with the content in the first cell of each row, and Y-axis labels with the first row contents. But how do I assign the values (from my CSV) to X, Y, Z coordinates? I am posting my code in my original post. Please see my edit above. Thanks again